# Change UInt32 to int64 for dt.isocalendar().week calculations

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, integer

For a data science project I used to calculate the week numbers through this code:

`df['Week_Nr'] = df['Date'].dt.week`

As this function is now depreciated I changed to

`df['Week_Nr'] = df['Date'].dt.isocalendar().week`

Yet my output used to be in int64 and now is in UInt32

And this is causing an error in a following calculation: "ValueError: DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float or bool.Did not expect the data types in fields Week_Nr"

So my question is how I can modify the isocalendar().week to give me a int64 output or how to transform the column to int64 as I have not been successful in finding the right code.
This code did not work: `df['Week_Nr'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Week_Nr'],errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try `.astype(numpy.int64)` or `.astype("int64")`